# What do the Hidamari Sketch "taglines" signify?

Tags: hidamari-sketch

The sequels to Hidamari Sketch all have "taglines" of one sort or the other. They are:

- Hidamari Sketch x 365
- Hidamari Sketch x Hoshimittsu
- Hidamari Sketch x SP
- Hidamari Sketch x Honeycomb

What do *365*, *hoshimittsu*, *SP*, and *honeycomb* signify and/or why were they chosen in particular?

Comment: SP stands for special, which makes sense because it's a special. 365 is probably signifying the number of days in a year, and Hoshimittsu literally means three stars, but I have no idea why they chose those names.

Comment: The Hoshimittsu series was literally written: できるかなって☆☆☆

Answer (score 5):

This answer is purely speculation so if somebody else posts an answer that has an official source, please feel free to accept that answer instead.

- 365 (Season 2): Some of these events take place before, during, and after season 1 if I remember correctly. So basically they're saying something like "we're going back to then and showing you all 365 days of their year!" (except they aren't literally showing you all 365, just more of what you saw in season 1)
- Hoshimittsu/☆☆☆ (Season 3): Three stars for season three
- Honeycomb (Season 4): There are six sides on a typical honeycomb, and there are six girls living at Hidamarisou. If this is the reasoning, they could've used this title for season 3 as well though.

As Logan M said in the comments, SP just stands for "special" (as opposed to a TV series). I don't think there is any significant meaning beyond that.

Comment: The hexagonal idea is interesting. Thank you :)

Comment: Hidamari Sketch x SP is a two-part television *special* so thus the SP.

Comment: As for Season 4, the Japanese verb [はにかむ](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8B%E3%82%80&eng=&dict=edict) (*hanikamu*) may also have something to do with it.

Comment: @yibe I can't really see a connection between the other はにかむ and Hidamari (or even that season in particular)

Comment: The word はにかむ is likely to be used to describe the cuteness of a girl acting bashfully, so I thought it might fit this anime featuring cute girls. (FWIW, [the title banner](http://www.tbs.co.jp/anime/hidamari/images/h1_img.jpg) says "hanikamu" rather than "honeycomb.")

Comment: Also, I've just found information about the title of Season 2 in [this Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A0%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%81_(%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1)), which says: `「365」とは1年の365日と人間の平熱である36.5℃との2つの意味があり、蒼樹自身の案によるものである` "*365* has two meanings: one is the number of days in a year; the other is 36.5 C, the average human temperature. This was proposed by Aoki Ume herself." So... Ume-sensei and the Hidamari anime staff may like titles with a double meaning.